# Are there any power outlets and Wi-Fi hotspots on the Zurich-Milan train?

Tags: trains, switzerland, power, wifi

I'm wondering if there are power outlets on the SBB Zurich-Milan train.

[The SBB page on the topic](https://www.sbb.ch/en/business-travel/travel/international/italy.html) says:

> "Depending on the route and train type, you can enjoy the following services during your journey:" Power sockets (1st class)

It doesn't even mention Wi-Fi.

So the question is: are there any power outlets and Wi-Fi hotspots on the Zurich-Milan train?

Comment: Where is the question? :)

Comment: The question is in the title.

Comment: Looks much better now IMHO.

Comment: Some of the trains actually have (or used to have) wifi, but it's pretty useless as it will only show you a local website with the timetables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://www.sbb.ch/en/station-services/during-your-journey/our-trains/astoro.html  says:

> The Astoro fleet is used for international services on the north-south axis (Germany–Switzerland–Italy).

> Sockets (Swiss + Int.)

> Mobile signal amplifier

> WLAN

This apparently https://company.sbb.ch/en/the-company/projects/mittelland-region-and-the-ticino/neat/rolling-stock-for-passenger-services.html has been the case since December 2016.

Answer (score 3):

Trains from Zurich to Milan are serviced by a number of companies.

For routes that start with InterCity trains, Wi-Fi is offered in 1st class. [Source](https://www.sbb.ch/en/business-travel/travel/service-im-zug.html)

Routes using InterRegio have free Wi-Fi, RegioExpress trains may also have Wi-Fi, please confirm. [Source](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.przewozyregionalne.pl%2Finterregio-2014-nowy-rozklad-jazdy-nowe-mozliwosci)

I don't know about EuroCity trains.

Comment: But keep in mind that the majority of the time you will be in areas with almost no coverage. From Zug to Biasca you will get Edge and from time to time 3G (tested with Swisscom and Orange) but don't expect to be able to transfer a lot ...

Comment: @Matteo True, I'll add that in.

Comment: @Matteo Were you on a train with a booster?

Comment: Hi I don't know (even if there is the sticker on the door I never saw any difference). I travelled daily Bern-Zurich and I travel Zurich-Lugano every month. On the Gotthard track don't expect to get a lot of connectivity (I had to try three times to load this page to answer you :-)

Comment: And what about power?

Comment: Those pages are about Intercity trains within Switzerland. Most trains to Italy use [different rolling stock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisalpino).

Comment: This answer should be removed because if you check the source @Relaxed is correct.

Comment: If an answer is incorrect, the process is to downvote it, not remove it (or in a nicer way, comment on it and sometimes answering OP will edit / remove the answer)

Comment: @chx Is the updated answer good? Power info will be added later,

Comment: InterRegio, RegioExpress, InterCity and EuroCity are brands reflecting a type of service used by various train operators in Europe. But trains going under that name in different countries use completely different rolling stock. In Switzerland, most train sets used for domestic service (or links with Germany) can't go to Italy because of the different power. I haven't seen them yet but I think that since December this line uses the new ETR 610, but maybe some trains have regular “Eurofirma” coaches with a special locomotive.

Comment: In any case, I don't think that any of the IC2000 or ICN rolling stock ever goes to Italy so you can't assume that information about domestic trains, even with the same service type, automatically applies (incidentally I think a long-distance train going over the border would typically always be branded as “EuroCity” so I don't think you will find any InterCity or InterRegio service going further than Chiasso).

Comment: The upshot is that unfortunately I can't help you improve the answer but I still think it's incorrect or at least insufficiently documented :-(

Comment: What makes you believe that there are multiple companies on that route? All trains on that route are SBB trains when they are in Switzerland, and Trenitalia trains when in Italy. SBB trains typically have no on board WIFI, as most Swiss have unlimited data plans on their phones.